# System.out.println not working

Tags: java

I am using eclipse for long time and this never happened but I have this really simple program . And it doesnt display anything . what can be the reason ?

```
public class ReportGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("STARTING");
   }
}
```

Comment: How are you running it? Have you tried restarting eclipse? Do you get an error message?

Comment: have you attached a console to the vm configured in your eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `Window -> Show View -> Console` if the console is not visible

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing `javac ReportGenerator.java`, it is just building a .class file. You need to run `java ReportGenerator` to see the program working and therefore printing on the terminal in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Too many opened consoles in Eclipse?

Here is the reference: [http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-open_action.htm](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-open_action.htm)

Click the grey X until all of them are closed.